# Storyboard issues about Horizontal Space

Tags: ios, xcode

on "Your Second iOS App:storyboard"-Enabling the addition of new items chapter.
what i do is the same as the Xcode5 shows.
how can it be different.
it says, On the canvas, select both the label and the text field and click the pin constraint button in the lower-right corner of the canvas.

The pin constraint button is the middle button in the group that looks like this:

In the Pin menu that appears, choose Horizontal Spacing.

You should see something like this:

[image: the Xcode doc shows]

[image: the version on my Xcode5]

how can i do it that way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to set the space between the Label and the TextField.

To do this, select either one of them, then hold Ctrl, drag to the other one and select **Horizontal Spacing**. This should add a constraint. If you want to change about it, select the it and open the Attributes Inspector.